# Best practices: Restore activity state

Tags: android, android-activity

**Problem:**
When I rotate the phone the activity calls again onCreate.
In my onCreate I make one http request for a xml file using AsincTask and parse it to a list of objects, but when I rotate the app everything disapear. 
The AsincTask also seems to keep going for the destrocted activity taking to long to print the list, I have read something about using a fragment but I'm not sure.
I also have one location manager in onCreate but it will start again when i rotate.
I also put some text in a textview but it also disapear.

All of this also happen in every fragment i have, when I rotate.

Should i put all of this on onCreate?

So is even possible to keep data and the location manager or I have to restore it, and how (what are the possibilities and the best)?

How can i prevent from creating multiple AsincTask's?

Comment: In addition to that duplicate question-  you have two ways of doing it, the way Android wants you to do it (which can be a major PITA), or the way almost everyone ends up doing it if they have async tasks/threads (preventing this behavior in the first place).  There are rival groups of developers who passionately believe in both answers, its a great holy war of Android.

Comment: Check other best practices to store data on config change. visit [Keeping data view/layout in Android after screen rotate/activity destroyed](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29425998/2032561), posted a new answer.